# Rogue Query In Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

I am running with Symfony 2.7.12

Now I am moving over to use DQL in most places, however when I run this code,

```
 $Query  =   $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('c as Query')
                ->from('xxxBundle:Campaigns','c')
                ->leftJoin('c.ClientID', 'clients')
                ->leftJoin('clients.accounts', 'ac')
                ->groupBy('clients.id')
                ->addSelect('clients')
                ->addSelect('ac')
                ->addSelect('COUNT(c.ClientID) as total')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

I get a rogue query being listed in my profiler. This Query does point to a 'module' table. This table does have a 'Campaign ID' so it is linked to the Campaigns table.

However this table is not listed in the joins above. And in my YMAL files - not a big fan of annotations :( - I have no fetch set.

I have tried to add a fetch to the module table (which is linked to the Campaigns with a One to One relationship) to both, one side or the other, with no effect. I have also tried setting this to 'extra_lazy', to no effect.

Has anyone else come across this?

Or does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to this problem. Not sure if this is the best but it dose not seem to break the code when I run the code to 'look' up form the 'module' table, but it does remove the rogue query.

I had setup this with one-to-one bidirectional link. I have now changed that to a unidirectional setup. This seems to work without the rouge query and does not break the site!

Thanks